# Why does piping Get-PSSession to Exit-PSSession not work?

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a new Powershell session like so:

```
New-PSSession -ConnectionUri https://myserver:12345 -Credential myserver\username -Authentication default
```

This is working fine, I can do `Get-PSSession` and it provides me with that one session. However, when trying to pipe the result to `Exit-PSSession` things go haywire. So this:

```
Get-PSSession | Exit-PSSession
```

Or this:

```
Get-PSSession 1 | Exit-PSSession
```

Will give an error:

> Exit-PSSession : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

I've tried fixing/understanding this by doing `Get-PSSession | Get-Member` which confirms that a proper object is returned from the first command.

I've also tried `Get-Help Exit-PSSession`, and saw that it has only `[<CommonParameters>]`, which makes me wonder about its purpose in the first place (it's probably a commandlet to exit the PSSession you're currently in?). In any case, this does explain why piping to that commandlet didn't work.

I've also checked `Get-Help Disconnect-PSSession`, but that just *disconnects* and leaves the PSSession around, it seems.

Bottom line: I (think I) am looking for the *opposite* of `New-PSSession`, but can't seem to find it. **What's the proper way to get rid of a PSSession?**

Comment: `Exit-PSSession` means "take me away from the current remote session", it wouldn't make sense to specify a specific PSSession instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not looked closely enough. Don't forget, it's easy to get all cmdlets related to a certain subject by doing something like this:

```
 Get-Help PSSession
```

This gets a list of all cmdlets with "PSSession" it its name. If you carefully review the output, there's `Exit-PSSession` and `Disconnect-PSSession`, but there's one more: `Remove-PSSession`. If view [the extended help](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849722.aspx) you'll see that it does a bit more than its name may imply (emphasis mine):

> The Remove-PSSession cmdlet **closes Windows PowerShell sessions (PSSessions) in the current session**. It stops any commands that are running in the PSSessions, ends the PSSession, and releases the resources that the PSSession was using. If the PSSession is connected to a remote computer, Remove-PSSession also closes the connection between the local and remote computers.

So it doesn't just "remove" the PSSession from sight, but it also closes the session and disconnects from the remote computer.

Piping from `Get-PSSession` will work as expected:

```
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```